# How to compute outer product between vectors with broadcast and batch?

Tags: python, math, pytorch, linear-algebra

Is there any operation that can achieve the following:

```
import torch

batch_size = 2
seq_len = 2
dim = 3
# batch of squences of embedding vecs:
x = torch.rand([batch_size, seq_len, dim])
# batch of target embedding vecs:
y = torch.rand([batch_size, dim])

# the computation I want to achieve:
print(torch.outer(x[0][0], y[0]))
print(torch.outer(x[0][1], y[0]))
print(torch.outer(x[1][0], y[1]))
print(torch.outer(x[1][1], y[1]))
print()
```

What I've tried but failed: `torch.einsum('bij, bj->bij', x, y))`.

Comment: Can you write down what you want to do mathematically? i.e. out[i, j, k] = ???

Comment: try `torch.einsum('abc, ad -> abcd', x, y)`